# Firebase onChildChanged returns null DataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this firebase database

[image]

and I have assigned listner to the field `driverId` to check if it's been changed by this code

```
myReq = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("requests").child(userId);
myReq.addChildEventListener(this);
```

then I implemented onChildChanged like this

```
 @Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


    String driverID = dataSnapshot.child("driverId").getValue(String.class);

    Toast.makeText(PlacesDemo.this, "GREAT " + driverID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

then when i change the `driverId` it's been trigged but passing a null DataSnapshot the `Toast`appears ( GREATE NULL)

Am I using a wrong listener or there's something else ?

Comment: You wanna check the driverid values right ?

Comment: yes I want to get the new changed value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `onChildChanged` is called, the `dataSnapshot` is the child that changed, not the parent node that you set the listener on.

So when you change the driverId in this case, the `dataSnapshot` is just giving you the new driverId and value. The driverId entry doesn't itself have another child called also called "driverId", hence the `NULL`when you ask for that. You need to ask directly for the value of the `dataSnapshot`:

```
String driverID = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

An alternative resolution would be to add the listener to the "requests" node itself instead of listening only to this specific 'request'; the `dataSnapshot`(ie. child) would then be all of the request data (the VRFq.. key and all of its children). You could then use `dataSnapshot.child("driverId")...` etc to get the data from the snapshot.

Comment: that makes many things clear to me , thanks a lot , it works !

Answer (score 2):

In the code you posted, `mReq` is a reference to the $userId child of `requests`.  That node has children: driverId, to, from, userId.

When you add a child listener to `mReq`, the callbacks fire for each of the four children. You could filter for changes to `driverId` using this code:

```
@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("driverId")) {
        String driverID = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Toast.makeText(PlacesDemo.this, "GREAT " + driverID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Another option is to use a `ValueEventListener` on the `driverId` location itself.

Comment: I know it is not related.. but Why the previous child's key is returned in OnChildChanged? Is there any use of it?

Comment: @user2399432: Good question.  I don't know.

Comment: @qbix you were my last hope!

Comment: @user2399432: Have you posted it as an SO question?  I would guess someone knows.

Comment: @qbix I tried to search for it.. I didn't find anything.. I wanted to avoid making a duplicate question so since I found this I thought about to ask.. I will ask a question to SO!

Answer (score 2):

There is another case when one could get a null response, even though the **remote** database has children.

If you have `database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);`, you might have a case where locally there are no children, but on remote will be, until next sync.

Use `database.getReference("your_node").keepSynced(true);` to always get the latest data on remote.